# Add dependency without being a child module

Tags: java, module, maven

I have 2 projects which results  WAR and JAR

in Order to build WAR i need the JAR .. so i need a dependency such that when i try to build the war automatically it should build the JAR and place it in the lib(or Repository)

Help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
---Parent POM
   |
   |-web module
   |      |
   |      --dependency of jar
   |-jar module
```

You need to configure multi module maven project

**Also See:**

- [having-a-maven-project-build-its-own-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330222/having-a-maven-project-build-its-own-dependencies/4391003#4391003)
- [Guide to Working with Multiple Modules](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)

Answer (score 1):

*I understand the title of you question "Add dependency without being a child module" in this way: you have two independent maven projects, and you do not want to put them in one project.*

Build the Jar project by `mvn install` this put it in your local repository, then you could add it like a normal dependency to your war project.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can just include the JAR-project as a pom-dependency.

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
  <version>version</version>
 </dependency>
```

However you might need to configure some dependency management in a POM-file where each project is as a module:

```
<modules>
  <module>my-project</module>
  <module>another-project</module>
</modules>
```

For more information see [this link](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Management).

As you stated, if you don't want to use the module management you may just install the JAR with maven install. See the answer made to your last question.