# In Maven How to build the dependent projects that are added as the dependencies in the main project when building the main project?

Tags: java, maven

I have 3 independent projects in my main project. When I want to add the dependencies of these projects to main project, then first I am building the dependent projects and then finally building the main project.
Is there is a way to build the dependent projects at the time of building the main project?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, use a multi-module project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <artifactId>someName</artifactId>
  <name>someName</name>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>dependentProject1</module>
    <module>dependentProject2</module>
    <module>mainProject</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: ya i know this is for multi module project........... but i have 3 independent projects A, B and C . C Contains the dependencies A and B that is i added dependencies externally to project C. My problem is when i am building the project C then the projects A and B are also to be build and their dependencies should be added at the time of C build process only

Comment: If you create a multi-module project you will get just that. Add dependencies to A and B in C and when building the multi-module project first A and B will be built and used as dependency in C.

Answer (score 3):

In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519542/in-maven-how-to-build-the-dependent-projects-that-are-added-as-the-dependencies#comment7688563_6519693) you specified your question a bit clearer: "My problem is when i am building the project C then the projects A and B are also to be build and their dependencies should be added at the time of C build process only". You have dependencies, want to build the dependencies on building the project, but you do not want to use a [multi-module project](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects).

Want you want to do is not possible. I had a similar question, and found this clear answer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4398836/1678525). Most other answers and comments suggest to have a multi project structure or to orchestrate the different (independent) builds with an ant script.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain better your situation (include the pom.xml)...maybe what you need is this http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects

Comment: i have 3 independent projects A, B and C . C Contains the dependencies A and B that is i added dependencies externally to project C. My problem is when i am building the project C then the projects A and B are also to be build and their dependencies should be added at the time of C build process only..............

Answer (score 0):

In child project you can add

```
<groupId>com.childproj.service</groupId>
<artifactId>A</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

And in parent project you can do like

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.childproj.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @krishna prasad above code will add reference of one project to another.

Comment: This does not build the project A, it only references it. So any changes done to A without explicitly building it won't be reflected.