# How to compile dependency in maven?

Tags: maven

Scenario:

I have a main level project A and within A , two child projects B and C worked on by different developers , but they agree on the abstraction through common interfaces.

B depends on C (dependency).
In B's pom I added

```
<dependency> .. details of project C..</dependency> .
```

Doing this, maven inserts the dependencies fine  except that project C is not recompiled.

I want project C to automatically re-compile every time I compile B.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to build B and automatically build it's dependencies you can use the advanced options of the maven reactor like  --also-make-dependents .

```
mvn clean install --projects B --also-make
```

Or [short](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-embedder/cli.html)

```
mvn clean install -pl B -am
```

That will compile all submodules of A whose B depends on .
There are a useful post on sonatype blog on the advanced options of maven reactor.
http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/

Comment: Note: use `--also make` NOT `--also-make-dependents`. The latter is to make anything that is depending on B whereas the former is to make anything that B depends on: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

Comment: @SQC: Is it possible to build a subset of dependencies?

Comment: there's a mssing dash : it's ``--also-make `` and not ``-also-make``.

Answer (score 10):

List projects B and C as modules in the pom of the project A. Now when you build project A, it should build project B and C automatically and in the correct order.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>multi</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <modules>
        <module>B</module>
        <module>C</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: I have a pom similar to this. This is not what I want though as I don't want to recompile all the projects from the top level directory. (Assume there are many modules C,D,E,F and B only depends on some modules C and E).

Answer (score 1):

I often use Maven reactor plugin to deal with these type of problems. This plugin even covers tough requirements that a complex project with many sub modules in a complex structure may has.
See [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-reactor-plugin/examples.html) for examples.

For above situations, using

```
mvn reactor:make -Dmake.folders=B
```

to build B and C (and all dependencies of B if any).

Hope this helpful.