# Maven: How to compile, create and include a jar file while building a different maven war module?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have the following project structure in maven:

```
Project-Master
--Subproject1-Master
----Module1
----Module2
--Subproject2-Master
----Module3
----Module4
```

Module 1 is resulting in a jar file. Module 4 ist resulting in a war file.

Now I want if I install Module 4, that Module 1 will compile its source code, create the jar file and this jar file should be included in the war file of Module 4.

Thank you for your replies!

Comment: use ant script to copy neccessary file and deploy as you need

Comment: What's wrong with adding Module 1 as a dependency of Module 4?

Comment: If I add Module 1 as a dependency of module 4, then the artifact will not be found, as the jar file is not created at this time. :(

Comment: If both sub project 1 and 2 depend on module 1, then perhaps you should move it up in the hierachy - directly below master?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the change in the structure as Subproject 1 is an web application with module 1 (source code) und module 2 (config). The same configuration for Subproject 2.

Comment: maybe u'r looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9173130/1338732

Comment: Finally I found a solution...

I created a "dummy" Module with the name "Module 1" (just the folder and the pom.xml) directly under "Subproject2-Master". In the pom.xml from "Subproject2-Master", I linked the dummy module as an additional module of "Subproject2-Master".
Within the dummy module, I call the maven-complile-plugin and the build-helper-maven-plugin which points to the source folder of the original Modul 1 source code.

Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

a) Attach the sources to the build in Module 1 using the mechanism described here (inside the module 1 pom.xml):

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html#Installing_the_sources_along_with_your_artifact

b) Reference module 1 twice from module 2, once as regular jar, once with classifier `sources` (inside the module 4 pom.xml)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>your.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>module1</artifact>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>your.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>module1</artifact>
  <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your answer correctly. Regarding a) do you mean to do this in the pom.xml of module 4? And b) ist this also in the pom.xml of module 4?

Comment: a) is in module 1, b) is in module 4

Comment: I doesn't work. Maven tries to download the artifact from our nexus, where the jar file doesn't exists. So I get an "Failed to resolve artifact" exception.