# Maven not detecting dependencies in Reactor build for modules?

Tags: java, maven

[image]

From the `MainProjectModule` folder I run

`mvn clean package -pl MainModuleLeaderArtifcatId -amd -am`.

The problem is, the `reactor build order` does **not** include `DEPENDENCY2` for some odd reason.

The error I get is:

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project MainModuleLeader. The following artifacts could not be resolved: Dependency2
```

I have added it in the POMs for the submodule

What could be causing this?

Comment: The error implies that the dependency is included and evaluated, but Maven cannot find the artifact of that dependency. You likely need to specify the path to the dependency's pom file and it needs to be buildable. The error will probably also go away if you build dependency2 on its own, because then Maven will find it in your artifact cache (~/.m2 on MacOs and Linux)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, your build order can be incorrect. First compile your submodules and try the main module after that.

Comment: Hi @mceviker. Pls leave comments as such, not as answers.

Comment: Sometimes SO does it automatically, I dont know why it did not do it in this case. Anyways I changed my language to look like an answer :)

Comment: Thanks, how can I do that in one line altogether?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167015/how-to-compile-dependency-in-maven please check this